# Executing a different program from my C program

Tags: c, shell, execution

I am writing a basic shell in Linux as a hobby, I want to start working on program execution, but have no idea on how to do this. I have seen `execp()` and its various brothers and sisters, but apparently that forces the kernel to drop the currently running process, in this case my shell, and continue with the new process.

So basically all I need is a function that I can use to call a command such as `ls` or `cd` have it execute and then return to my shell.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new process with `fork` and then call `exec`.

Comment: Okay, so create a new instance of my shell or just a simple program using `fork` then in that process call the `exec` function from that?

If so, I cannot believe I did not think of that!

Thanks.

Comment: You fork first and then use exec to invoke the command you want.  Note that this will not work for `cd`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will get a few more suggestions and then test each method.

Answer (score 2):

ouah's answer is essentially correct, but it won't work for `cd`.  Your shell needs to implement that as a builtin command (i.e. the shell needs to contain the code for `cd`.

The reason for this is that `fork` first creates a new copy of the current process (the running instance of the shell, in this case).  Then exec overwrites the new process with the executable you want to run.  When the command finishes, the new process terminates and goes away.  If you use this for `cd` it will change the working directory of the new process but leave the working directory of the old process (the shell) totally untouched.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. I will do more research on the `fork()` function then.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
if (fork ()==0) {
    execl ("/bin/sh",NULL);
}
```

This will create the new process (an exact copy of already running one), then replace it with the new one.
Please note this might require some workarounds in some environments where CPU does not fully support virtual memory, and your original process is so big that you can not duplicate it.

Comment: Will this print the output of the new process, in your case `/bin/sh` to STDOUT ?

Comment: Yes, the console of the newly ran process (i.e., STDOUT and STDIN) will be the same as the original process.

Comment: Okay, well it sort of seems to work.

I get this error upon calling the function.


A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.

This is calling the `ls` command from the `execl()` function...